# Position center not top left corner of an image in css

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to position center not top left corner of an image in CSS?
I have an image that has other images on top of it (a map with points). The background image has a fixed size and I have set the location of the images that are on the top with css:

```
#map {
 width: 700px;
 height: 700px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.point {
 position: absolute;
 left: 39.9%;
 top: 81.9%;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

the size of the point is 20x20px so I subtracted 10px from the necessary location and then converted to %. Everything looks as it should.

I am trying to make the code work for smaller screens. I changed the width and height to max-width and max-height. Now the background adapts to the smaller screen, but because of those 20px I calculated in the position of the point, the smaller the screen gets, the further from the needed location the point goes.

The only solution I could think of was if I could set the position of points center with %, not the top left corner. Would it be possible? Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
left: calc(50% - 10px);
top: calc(50% - 10px);
```

Or

```
left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;
top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Is there a way to solve this so that the size of the point also decrease proportionally?

Comment: You can use vw and vh units to make the width and height of the point proportional to the window width and height (1vw means 1% of window width, 1vh means 1% window height). But then in the margins or the px inside the calc , you would have to use half the value you set as width and height for the image.